# Mostrar/ocultar mediante get

Tags: php

> El objetivo es mostrar un enlace u otro en función del valor que tome una variable enviada por get.

1. Al recargar la página si no existe el request de "valor", $valor  es
   FALSE. Como valor es false el enlace alta tiene clase visible y el enlace
   Cancelar tiene clase oculto
2. Al pinchar en Alta, enviamos por get true como valor de "valor" y al
   recargar la página se oculta el enlace Alta y es visible el enlace Cancelar
3. Al pinchar Cancelar, enviamos por get false como valor de "valor" y al
   recargar la página , aunque el $valor es false, SIGUE APARECIENDO EL ENLACE
   CANCELAR CON CLASE VISIBLE Y EL ALTA COMO OCULTO

PREGUNTA:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
         <meta charset="UTF-8">
         <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
         scale=1.0">
             <style>

                .oculto{
                    display:none;
                }
                .visible{
                    display:block;
                }


            </style>
    <title>Document</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <?php

        $valor = isset($_REQUEST["valor"]) ? $_REQUEST["valor"]:false;
        print $valor." valor";

   ?>
    <a href="get.php?valor=true" class=<?php echo $valor ? 
    'oculto':'visible'?>>Alta</a>
    <a href="get.php?valor=false" class=<?php 
     echo $valor ? 'visible':'oculto'?>>Cancelar</a>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu enlace Cancelar estás asignando 'false' al parámetro valor. Pero, ojo, cuando recibes el parámetro, ya sea usando $_GET o $_REQUEST, lo que recibes no es el valor booleano false, sino un dato de tipo cadena, que es 'false'.

Por tanto, estarías asignando a la variable $false el valor 'false' (cadena, no booleano).

Cuando evalúas $valor para pintar 'visible' o 'oculto', lo evalúas esperando que sea un dato booleano, pero es una cadena. Y todas las cadenas, excepto '', '0', ' ' y no sé si alguna más, se evalúan como true. Por tanto, tu 'false' es true, y por eso se pinta 'visible', llevándote a confusión.

Una solución es castear el dato cadena a bool, pero normalmente lo que se suele hacer es pasar los valores 0 y 1 en vez de false y true. Te pongo lo único que habría que cambiar:

```
<a href="get.php?valor=1" class="<?php echo $valor ? 
'oculto':'visible'; ?>">Alta</a>
<a href="get.php?valor=0" class="<?php 
 echo $valor ? 'visible':'oculto'; ?>">Cancelar</a>
```

Nota: También he añadido comillas a los valores de las propiedades class.

Comment: Gracias, mil por la respuesta. Sencilla, concisa, resolutiva, didáctica--->++